# truffle has not been deployed to detected network

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Is it possible to referer to a contract that has been deployed with 
Contract.new() with Contract.deployed() ?

When referencing .deployed() in my test it throws :

`has not been deployed to detected network (1501794786154)`

Obviously the code has been successfully deployed on the network ( in my deploy file i can get access to all the contracts address, can see the sucessfull transaction in Testrpc , etc ) .

Also the network id is the good one.

```
    module.exports = {
      networks: {
        development: {
          host: "localhost",
          port: 8545,
          network_id: "*" // Match any network id
        }
      }
    };
```

Lastly :
When i check the contract Build folder json file for the contract that is not recognized as deploy i can find :

```
"networks": {
    "1501794786154": {
```

So it is indeed deployed.

I've tried deleting the build folder and recompile again etc. as per

[Truffle Webpack starts with error: MetaCoin has not been deployed to detected network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/truffle-webpack-starts-with-error-metacoin-has-not-been-deployed-to-detected-ne)

Anybody has a pointer?

Comment: Perhaps you can do truffle migrate again (with 2_deploy_contracts.js properly set)

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes I've run into a similar issue where truffle doesn't detect changes in my contracts and either it doesn't compile it or, when it does, it doesn't migrate it (saying network is up to date).

You can try running truffle compile (and/or truffle migrate) with the --reset flag.

Comment: Wow.  This should be the first tip you learn with Truffle.  It's like "clean" for a C++ or similar project.  Thanks!

Comment: or even if `--reset` flag don't work then use `--reset --all`

Comment: very good tip, but on my case it also missed on 2_deploy_contract.js

Answer (score 9):

Your contract might not have been added to the truffle migrations deployer. You should check your file /migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var YourContractName = artifacts.require("./YourContractName.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
   .......;
   deployer.deploy(YourContractName);
};
```

Comment: oh damn, that was it!!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue today. For whatever reason truffle is not detecting any contracts deployed in `2_deploy_contracts.js` unless I explicitly specify the contract address using the `at()` function. I was able to get around this by deploying the contract in `1_initial_migration.js` instead and then redeploying all my contracts from scratch.

Comment: Welcome to the community :) refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) post formatting guide

Comment: Thank you Achala that is a helpful reference. For my post, was there a specific portion I could have formatted differently?

Comment: Actually your post need very less formatting to make it more readable. I may suggest some, anyway they are not essential :) Guide might help you when you are posting later.

Comment: This answer deserves a lot more credit. The `at` function, which takes the address of the deployed contract **as an explicit argument**, is perfect for this task. I'm not even sure what the `deployed` function is really good for. What if I have deployed more than one instance of the same contract?

Answer (score 5):

I've just solved the same problem by following steps:

1. in the `1_initial_migration.js` (or what ever the name of your
   deploy config file):

   ```
   var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Contract.sol");
   module.exports = function(deployer) {
     deployer.deploy(Contract);
   };
   ```
2. run command
   `truffle compile` and
   `truffle migrate --reset`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

1. Remove the build folder

   `rm -r build/`
   `truffle compile`
   `truffle migrate`
2. Use

   `truffle migrate --reset --all`

I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Change the metamask network from test net or main net to your localhost version