# Orders Facilitator Contract has not been deployed to detected network

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a simple contract to truffle.   This is very confusing now because truffle has it's own network built into it, yet the tutorial I'm following uses test-rpc.  I've looked at a few other [questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/truffle-has-not-been-deployed-to-detected-network) about this but none seem to address my specific issue.

I'm running the command:

```
test-rpc --network-id 1337
```

Inside of my project I've configured my truffle.js like so:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "1337"
    }
  }
};
```

Then I ran:

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate

truffle console
```

I check to verify my contract has been deployed in the console by running:

```
OrdersFacilitator.network_id
```

this returns `1337` yet when I run:

```
var facilitator;
OrdersFacilitator.deployed().then(x => facilitator = x);
```

I receive an error:

> Error: OrdersFacilitator has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

The weird thing is that when I run OrdersFacilitator.network_id it shows the proper networkId.   How can I fix this issue?